# How to test if file is a socket in command line?

Tags: macos, command-line

As titled. Is there a way to test in command line whether a file is a socket? By test I mean whether I can tell from the stdout, and not programmatically as in a bash script, although that's fine too. Btw, I am on a Mac (once in a while the commands are different). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A socket has "s" in the first permission flag:

```
ls -la X0 
srwxrwxrwx 1 paul hum 0 Jul 14 14:48 X0
```

You can test in bash with the `-S` switch:

```
if  [ -S /my/file.socket ] ; then
   # stuff
fi
```

Or the `find` command could be used to find any sockets in a directory:

```
find  . -type s
```

Answer (score 0):

test -S /var/run/some_socket_file

if $? == 0, this file is a socket file.